# Can a locally presentable category have a proper class of accessible localizations?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, locally-presentable-categories

**Question:** What is an example of a locally presentable category $\mathcal C$ such that there exists a proper class of accessible localizations $(\mathcal C \to \mathcal D_i)_{i < ORD}$?

In other words, $(D_i)_{i < ORD}$ should be a proper class of full reflective subcategories of $\mathcal C$ which are accessibly embedded in $\mathcal C$.

I'm also interested in the infinity-categorical setting, though I suspect it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A limit closure of a set of objects of a locally presentable category $\mathcal K$ is reflective. In this way one gets an increasing chain of reflective full subcategories of $\mathcal K$. If this chain stops $\mathcal K$ has a cogenerator. Since a category of groups does not have a cogenerator, it has a proper class of reflective full subcategories. These subcategories are accessibly embedded under Vopěnka's principle. I do not expect that Vopěnka's principle is needed but, at this moment, I do not see how to avoid it.

Comment: Don't we also get easy example assuming the negation of Vopenka ? if A is a non-accessible localization of C, then we can consider the class of localization of C at any *set* S of morphisms inverted by the reflection $C \to A$. If these only forms a set, as $A$ identifies with the localization at their unions, it would make $A$ a localization at a set of arrows hence an accessible localization.

Comment: So, there is an example in any model of ZFC. Can one do it without mentioning VP at all?